# GoLang GORM Update vs Updates

Tags: go, orm, sql-update, go-gorm

I have function that must update my object by struct. When I use code with Updates, it cause an error like "reflect: call of reflect.Value.SetInt on struct Value". Otherwise with Update it works clean.

My code:

```
type UpdateProducRequest struct {
    ID        string `json:"id"`
    BalanceID string `json:"balance_id"`
    IsActive  bool   `json:"is_active"`
    Type      int    `json:"type"`
    Price     int64  `json:"price"`
}

func (s Storage) UpdateProduc(req *UpdateProducRequest) (resp *models.Product, err error) {
    // this clause panic
    // err = db.Model(&models.Product{}).Where("id=?", req.ID).Updates(req).Take(&resp).Error

    // this works fine
    err = db.Model(&models.Product{}).
        Where("id=?", req.ID).
        Update("balance_id", req.BalanceID).
        Update("is_active", req.IsActive).
        Update("type", req.Type).
        Update("price", req.Price).
        .Take(&resp).Error
    return
}
```

What I must to do for using Updates because using Update is difficult in my project because of many fields in some structs.

Comment: you can use Updates with Select or Omit, to include or exclude some fields .
https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Update-Selected-Fields

Comment: Updates takes a map[string] (pairs of FIELDNAME, VALUE) that get parsed to a SET DB Call. Either expose a function on your UpdateProducRequest that builds such a map or use db.Save(&models.Product{}) with a properly set object.

Comment: @GreenChicken through documentation omit or select are not required (how I understand) through example gorm.io/docs/update.html#Updates-multiple-columns

Comment: @AndyTroschke through documentation updates accept structs too, what about save, it need each fields, so if I don't have BalanceID in update req, then .Save(req) makes balanceID equal to null

Comment: @SunatSaidov indeed, Updates accept a struct. However, when I fiddled with this I also had issues giving it a non-equal struct, which makes me believe that Updates only accepts a struct of an equal type to the type you intend to update.

Ideally, to properly control what fields can be updates, you should expand your Request type to build a map for updates to properly work. You can use this to implement field validation as well, which I'll recommend given the field names.

Comment: @AndyTroschke thanks for advice. Now I using converter for this, but still wait for answers

Answer (score 0):

this is how I did it in my e-commerce app. You can try this one.

> Flow is: manager->service->repository.

repository.go

```
func (r *Repository) UpdateWithFields(product *models.Product, fields interface{}) error {
        return r.Connection.PsqlDB().Model(product).Updates(fields).Error
    }
```

service.go

```
func (s *Service) UpdateWithFields(product *models.Product, form UpdateForm) error {
    var fields = map[string]interface{}{
        "name": form.Name,
    }
    if form.Description != nil {
        fields["description"] = form.Description
    }
    if form.Category != nil {
        fields["category"] = form.Category
    }
    if form.PixelImage != nil {
        fields["pixel_image"] = form.PixelImage
    }
    if form.IsActive != nil {
        fields["is_active"] = *form.IsActive
    }
    return s.Repository.UpdateWithFields(product, fields)
}
```

manager.go

```
func (s *ProductManager) Update(form products.UpdateForm, id int) (*models.Product, error) {
    product, err := s.ProductService.FindById(id)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New(utils.ProductNotFound)
    }

    err = s.ProductService.UpdateWithFields(product, form)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
        return nil, errors.New(utils.ProductUpdateError)
    }
    return product, nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but my goal is writing less code, and solution with few Update call looks easier (Update has nil or zero value check). But I chose converting all my request structs to maps by helper func and don't do it manually. It is temp solution and I hoped I'll get something better soon